# Parsing difficult XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, rows

I have to parse really terribly formed XML. I was wondering if anybody had a way of parsing it without having to go line-by-line and search for text between the ""

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stats>
  <title>Soccer Match 1</title>
  <rows>
    <match>
      <row column1="" column2="Pre Game" />
      <row column1="101" column2="105" />
      <row column1="ARS" column2="MNU" />
      <row column1="0" column2="0" />
      <row column1="0" column2="POSSESSION %" column3="0" />
      <row column1="0 (0)" column2="SHOTS (ON TARGET)" column3="0 (0)" />
      <row column1="0" column2="CORNERS" column3="0" />
      <row column1="0" column2="FOULS" column3="0" />
      <row column1="0/0" column2="YELLOW/RED" column3="0/0" />
    </match>
  </rows>
</stats>
```

Comment: What is terrible here? Please, show what you have tried, and explain what exactly you want to parse from this file. You want to get  `Soccer Match 1` string?

Comment: Google it, and you will find thousands of tutorial on XML parsing

Comment: can you send some code to see how to try parse this xml?

Comment: @lazy you're right, the XML is valid, but you must admit the design is terrible.

Comment: @CodeCaster agree. And `row` tags are not highlighted with red color!

Comment: Sorry when I said formed I should have said designed. This is is the nodes aren't titled correctly. If I was creating it for instance I would have a node called "Possession". I have it working already I'm just loading in each match as a string and searching for the "" and loading them into a struct I made

Comment: @user3087217 it would be very nice if you will paste your code into question (that's a common way to ask question here - you show what you tried and explain problem)

Answer (score 3):

Whats bad about the XML? I'd use Linq2Xml to parse it - [here is a tutorial on how to do that](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/218979-linq-to-xml/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Linq2XML I'd use an [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Very interesting :) Can you explain your choise?

Comment: Both have their merits - performance is similar - personally I find Linq2Xml easier to work with, but both are better than writing your own parser :) https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/performance-linq-to-sql-vs

Comment: Yes, I'd never *ever* try to write my own XML parser. Personally I like `XmlDocument` better because I feel "close to the source". You could actually use Linq2XML, too.